# Limit DevExpress-WinForms TextEdit text to its Width, not MaxLenght

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, devexpress, textedit

I need to limit the 1 line text entered in a XtraGrid repository editor to its column fixed width. I cannot use a monospaced font and MaxLenght because this field will be shown in a report.
In KeyPress event handler I tried to create a Label, put the string on it and compare its PreferedSize.Width to the column's Width. It almost worked well but is not easy to control Paste operations if I have to remove the exceeding chars (f.ex.: if I change the text value, the cursor jumps to 0).
I also tried using ActiveEditor.CreateGraphics.MeasureString but cannot get it to draw(measure) the text the same way DevExpress does.
If I could catch a Before_WordWrap event it would be a solution.
Thank you.

Edited: I see, I have 2 negative votes because someone consider that I did not have enough effort to find the answer by my own, but I consider that the answer was not easy! I won't delete the thread because I think it could be useful to others.
Regards.

Comment: are you sure you can't use the maxlength property..? what is the field in the XTraGrid that you want to limit.. also is there an EventHandler where you can get the length of the Text and set the max length.. ????

Comment: The field is an invoice's article description that will be shown in a Crystal Reports report. I cannot use multiline fields either.

Comment: what is the max length that you are wanting the text that was entered to be.. can you post the code where you are entending to have this functionality and I can post something that I am texting to see if it will work for you..? inside of the grid where it's being populated there has to be an onChanged event for that field in regards to the Text.. this is where you should actually have the check done.. multiline is not the issue ..it's more of string length there are several ways to handle this but would really need to see the code snippet that you are working with

Comment: excuse me DJ KRAZE, I had to go yesterday. Thanks to your onChanged clue I've got the solution. I post it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Why do I have 2 negative votes in my question? What did I wrong? Please tell me to avoid it next time. I'm not used to ask in forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DJ KRAZE's suggestion I got it.
On the EditValueChanging event of the repository TextEdit, I assign e.NewValue to a DevExpress Label and compare its PreferredSize.Widht with the column Width. If it is greater, I remove chars until it's smaller and assign the text to e.NewValue.
The cursor was jumping to 0, so (according to DevExpress FAQ) I had to do an Invoke to change TextEdit.SelectionStart property. Damn! VB-2008 doesn't accept anonymous methods and had to put it appart :)
Thanks.
Regards.

```
Private Sub RepositoryItemTextEditDescrip_EditValueChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs) Handles RepositoryItemTextEditDescrip.EditValueChanging
    Static lbl As New DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl
    Dim tx As DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit = sender
    Dim s As String = e.NewValue.ToString.Split(vbCr)(0)
    lbl.Text = s
    lbl.Font = tx.Font
    If lbl.PreferredSize.Width >= colDescrip.Width - 15 Then
        Do Until lbl.PreferredSize.Width <= colDescrip.Width - 15 Or s.Length = 0
            s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1)
            lbl.Text = s
        Loop
    End If
    Dim i As Integer = tx.SelectionStart
    e.NewValue = s
    BeginInvoke(New Action(Of TextEdit, Integer)(AddressOf sbTxSelectIndx), New Object() {tx, i})
End Sub
Private Sub sbTxSelectIndx(ByVal tx As TextEdit, ByVal i As Integer)
    tx.Select(i, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Voting up is always encouraged.. I am glad that I was able to lend you a clue.. I know VB as well but prefer to stay far far away from it..LOL once again ..glad I could help point you in the right direction...

Comment: Thank you again. I like VB, I'm always messed with those {} everywhere in C#.

Comment: Thanks Ivan I appreciate that and It was a pleasure helping you